# Loading a js file into my html script tag

Tags: javascript, html

My file structure is as follows:

```
njtest 
  -> server.js
uripage
  -> landing.html
```

I'm trying to call a function from server.js in my landing.html using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ njtest/server.js">
```

Every time i receive the following error from Firefox browser:

> Loading failed for the  with source “file:///njtest/server.js”.

Comment: Is the extra space in your real file?

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../njtest/server.js">
```